# @API for text variables

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I'm trying to associated lightning input values to be used as variables

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement,wire, api} from 'lwc';
import getClass from "@salesforce/apex/SchedulableClasses.SchedulableClasses";
import setPlan from "@salesforce/apex/Plan.Plan";
export default class LightningExampleInputDateTime extends LightningElement {
    @wire (getClass) apexclass;
    @api jobName ;
    @api minute;
    @api hour;
    $d='0'+this.minute+this.hour+'* * ?';
    $jobName=this.jobName;
    handleClick(){
        setPlan({jobName:this.jobName,d:this.d,scheduleName:'PlanTest'})
           .then(result => {
              alert('Success');
           })
           .catch(error => {
               alert('Fail');
                   });
     }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <h2>Planning Apex Action    </h2>
    <div>
        <lightning-input label="Job Name" >{jobName}</lightning-input>
        </div>
    <h3>Apex Action</h3>
    <template if:true={apexclass.data}>
            <template for:each={apexclass.data} for:item="apex">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox" key={apex.Id} label={apex.Name} value={apexName}></lightning-input>
            </template>
    </template>
    <div>
        <h3>Time of execution</h3>
        <lightning-input name="hours" label="Hour" value={hour}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input name="minutes" label="Minute" value={minute} ></lightning-input>
    </div>

<lightning-button label="Submit" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
    </div>

</template>
```

The handle function works ok. But after trying to set the varibles with api and inserting values from the html using the lightning input the function isn't working. The alert that i'm getting is fail which signifies an error. Which i didn't have before without the @api

Comment: What's the problem and the question?

Comment: @MartinLezer it is mentioned i'm getting an error after adding the api but i'm using it the same way it is explained in the documentation

Comment: What error message you get? can you provide exact verbatim?

Comment: Also I dont see any onchange handler on lightning-input that will update the values back in javascript

Comment: The error you get is probably because your @api variables are never set. Their values are undefined. In LWC, the binding is only one way. ie, only the javascript can update the values for the view. If you want the view to update the values you have to add some change handler to your inputs.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal the errors that are showen in VScode are indefined values for result and error in the javascript and also unexpected alert for the alerts inside these two values. I just noticed i missed the onchange handler i'll be adding it now.

Comment: @MartinLezer after adding the handlers it works perfectly i added the answer and the final version of the Javascript and HTML

Comment: @RamiAbouKhalil Great ! Good job.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the end i was missing the change handler for the javascript 
Here is the new and final javascript and html that works perfectly

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement,wire, api} from 'lwc';
import getClass from "@salesforce/apex/SchedulableClasses.SchedulableClasses";
import setPlan from "@salesforce/apex/Plan.Plan";
export default class LightningExampleInputDateTime extends LightningElement {
    @wire (getClass) apexclass;
    @api jobName ;
    @api minute='0';
    @api hour='0';

    handleClick(){
        setPlan({jobName:this.jobName,d:'0 '+this.minute+' '+this.hour+' * * ?',scheduleName:'PlanTest'})
           .then(result => {
              alert('Success');
           })
           .catch(error => {
               alert('Fail');
                   });
     }
     handleNameChange(event){
         this.jobName = event.target.value;
     }
     handleMinuteChange(event){
         this.minute= event.target.value;
     }
     handleHourChange(event){
         this.hour=event.target.value;
     }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <h2>Planning Apex Action    </h2>
    <div>
        <lightning-input label="Job Name" onchange={handleNameChange} value={jobName}></lightning-input>
        </div>
    <h3>Apex Action</h3>
    <template if:true={apexclass.data}>
            <template for:each={apexclass.data} for:item="apex">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox" key={apex.Id} label={apex.Name} value={apexName}></lightning-input>
            </template>
    </template>
    <div>
        <h3>Time of execution</h3>
        <lightning-input name="hours" label="Hour" onchange={handleHourChange} value={hour}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input name="minutes" label="Minute" onchange={handleMinuteChange} value={minute} ></lightning-input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <lightning-button label="Submit" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
    </div>

</template>
```

Comment: This code will not work. Variables with @api are read-only to the component.

Comment: @KevinVenkiteswaran this code is working and perfectly

Comment: When you run it in dev mode you’ll find warnings in the browser’s console. Prod mode (for now) doesn’t enforce those restrictions but may in the future at which time the code will not work. Eg assigning to this.minute will have no effect.

Comment: See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_props_public

Comment: @KevinVenkiteswaran can you specify the warning that shows you. And also your document is about setters and getters, and to use them properly.